# Do you need to purchase TFS separately if you already bought Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, license, team-foundation-server

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (single license). I want to use Team Foundation Server (TFS). Do I have the right to install TFS on the same machine than Visual Studio 2010, if I would be the only person¹ to use TFS?

From what I've seen, TFS is [marked as a feature](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/overview) of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, not a separate product you have to purchase after buying Visual Studio.

On the other hand, the only DVD I have has only Visual Studio on it, and no TFS (unless it's hidden somewhere).

---

<sup>¹ I work as a freelancer, so I would be the only one using TFS. I know it's for teams; if I want to use it alone, it's because I want to have enough experience with it for my future career.</sup>

Comment: TFS runs on SharePoint. I have no knowledge of the product except that it exists, but perhaps you need to download it from MSDN using your credentials acquired using the Ultimate licence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask a licensing expert for the definite choice, but as I understand it an MSDN subscription comes with a TFS CAL. (There is no TFS server licence, if you install TFS on a single server – data and application tiers on one system – it includes SQL Server Standard for TFS use only.)

Otherwise a pack of ten TFS CALs can be purchased.

It does seem strange to purchase Visual Studio *without* MSDN, it also seems strange to buy either retail: a two or three year open licence for a single instance of VS+MSDN (at various levels) is available and is considerable cheaper over that period.